# Multiple nested GroupBy to turn tabular data into a class

Tags: c#, linq, nested

I have data that is in tabular format like

```
    ID | Category  | Group  | Platform | Count
   --------------------------------------------        
    1  | Accepted  | Public | Windows  | 20

    1  | Completed | Debug  | Mac      | 15
```

And such.  There will be one row for each unique combination of these values (i.e. the same ID can have many Categories, and the Cateogories can have many Groups, and the Groups can have many Platforms, etc.

I have a class that I want to map this to where I start with a class that has just a string Platform, and a Count.  There is then a class that has a string Group and a List of Platforms, then a class which has a string Category and List of Groups, and so on.

I am trying to figure out how to group the data into a format that can be parsed into this class in C#.  I am currently doing this:

```
var data = falloffData.GroupBy(sk => new { sk.SID})
    .Select(sg => new
    {
        SID = sg.Key.SID,
        Group = sg.GroupBy(ak => new { ak.AGroup })
        .Select(ag => new
        {
            AGroup = ag.Key.AGroup,
            Category = ag.GroupBy(ck => new { ck.Category })
            .Select(cg => new
            {
                Category = cg.Key.Category,
                Platform = cg.GroupBy(pk => new { pk.Platform })
                .Select(pg => new
                {
                    Platform = pg.Key.Platform,
                    Count = pg.Sum(c => c.TotalCount)
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

This groups correctly, but I am ending up with an IEnumerable with a lot of anonymous types like:

> { AGroup = "Production", Category =
>   {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIteratorf__AnonymousType4,
>   Scratch.Program.FalloffItem>, <>f__AnonymousType5f__AnonymousType7>>>} }

I am unclear of how I would parse this into my C# class.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a lot of anonymous types because you are creating a lot of anonymous types.

If you want to select/project in to concrete classes then you need to select into them and not use anonymous types.

**Given your classes**

```
internal class SomePlatform
{
  public string Platform { get; set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeCategory
{
  public string Category { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SomePlatform> Platforms { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeGroup
{
  public string AGroup { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SomeCategory> Categorys { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeClass
{
  public string SID { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SomeGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

**Projection example**

```
blah.GroupBy(sk => sk.SID) // Group
    .Select(sg => new SomeClass // Select into SomeClass
    {
      SID = sg.Key.SID,
      Groups = sg.GroupBy(ak => ak.AGroup) // Group
                .Select(ag => new SomeGroup // Select into SomeGroup
                 {
                    AGroup = ag.Key.AGroup,
                    Categorys = ag.GroupBy(ck => ck.Category)  // Group
                                 .Select(cg => new SomeCategory  // Select into SomeCategory
                                  {
                                     Category = cg.Key.Category,
                                     Platforms = cg.GroupBy(pk => pk.Platform) // Group
                                                  .Select(pg => new SomePlatform // Select into SomePlatform
                                                   {
                                                      Platform = pg.Key.Platform,
                                                      Count = pg.Sum(c => c.TotalCount)
                                                   })
                                  })
                 })
    });
```